# Android XML Processing with the XmlPullParser

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am following a tutorial from Coursera on how to Pull Parse an XML from the web. Beneath is the code. I have read on the web but I am having troubles implementing the PullParser when the .xml file is located in the assets folder and not online. The whole operation is done within an AsyncTask. What changes do I have to make to the code?

NetworkingAndroidHttpClientXMLActivity.java

```
package course.examples.networking.androidhttpclientxml;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.net.http.AndroidHttpClient;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;

public class NetworkingAndroidHttpClientXMLActivity extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        new HttpGetTask().execute();
    }

    private class HttpGetTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<String>> {

        // Get your own user name at http://www.geonames.org/login
        private static final String USER_NAME = "aporter";

        private static final String URL = "http://api.geonames.org/earthquakes?north=44.1&south=-9.9&east=-22.4&west=55.2&username="
                + USER_NAME;

        AndroidHttpClient mClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("");

        @Override
        protected List<String> doInBackground(Void... params) {
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL);
            XMLResponseHandler responseHandler = new XMLResponseHandler();
            try {
                return mClient.execute(request, responseHandler);
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<String> result) {
            if (null != mClient)
                mClient.close();
            setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    NetworkingAndroidHttpClientXMLActivity.this,
                    R.layout.list_item, result));
        }
    }
}
```

XMLResponseHandler.java

```
package course.examples.networking.androidhttpclientxml;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException;
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserFactory;

class XMLResponseHandler implements ResponseHandler<List<String>> {

    private static final String MAGNITUDE_TAG = "magnitude";
    private static final String LONGITUDE_TAG = "lng";
    private static final String LATITUDE_TAG = "lat";
    private String mLat, mLng, mMag;
    private boolean mIsParsingLat, mIsParsingLng, mIsParsingMag;
    private final List<String> mResults = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public List<String> handleResponse(HttpResponse response)
            throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
        try {

            // Create the Pull Parser
            XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
            XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // Set the Parser's input to be the XML document in the HTTP Response
            xpp.setInput(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity()
                    .getContent()));

            // Get the first Parser event and start iterating over the XML document 
            int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

            while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

                if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                    startTag(xpp.getName());
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                    endTag(xpp.getName());
                } else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                    text(xpp.getText());
                }
                eventType = xpp.next();
            }
            return mResults;
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void startTag(String localName) {
        if (localName.equals(LATITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingLat = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(LONGITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingLng = true;
        } else if (localName.equals(MAGNITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingMag = true;
        }
    }

    public void text(String text) {
        if (mIsParsingLat) {
            mLat = text.trim();
        } else if (mIsParsingLng) {
            mLng = text.trim();
        } else if (mIsParsingMag) {
            mMag = text.trim();
        }
    }

    public void endTag(String localName) {
        if (localName.equals(LATITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingLat = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(LONGITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingLng = false;
        } else if (localName.equals(MAGNITUDE_TAG)) {
            mIsParsingMag = false;
        } else if (localName.equals("earthquake")) {
            mResults.add(MAGNITUDE_TAG + ":" + mMag + "," + LATITUDE_TAG + ":"
                    + mLat + "," + LONGITUDE_TAG + ":" + mLng);
            mLat = null;
            mLng = null;
            mMag = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need a context (like an Activity), then you can do this:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("filename");
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput(is);
```

The rest should be the same.

Comment: What about the doInBackground() method what do I need to change since I'm getting the data from an asset and not from the web?

Comment: I would think the entirety of retrieving the resource and parsing it should go in `doInBackground()`, and you would make any UI updates in `onPostExecute()` with the results.